# read() are not reading the complete http response

Tags: c, sockets

I am getting start to socket use in C programming language. I am trying to make an simple http request and store the buffer obtained from read() in my buffer. For this, I use pointers/`realloc()`, the C programs works fine, compile no errors, but it is reading only a part of the http response.

For example, if I try to get the binary of google's logo: http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png the Content-Length say 7007 bytes, but `strlen(buffer)` say 5146 for me.I belive that the mistake out here is my `buf_size` and `realloc()` why `bytesreaded` is 7337 the 330 bytes I belive that is of headers.

Here is my code:

```
char *
httpget(const char * domain, const int port, const char * headers)
{
    int sockfd; /* Socket file descrption */
    int buf_size = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;

    struct sockaddr_in  sock_addr; 
    struct hostent  *   host;

    char * buffer;
    char * newbuf;
    char * tbuf;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, /* Uses IPV4 Internet protocols */
                    SOCK_STREAM, /* Uses the TCP (Transfer Communication Protocol) */
                    0  /* "0" for socket () function choose the correct protocol based on the socket type. */
                    );

    if( sockfd == -1 )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    host = gethostbyname(domain);

    if( NULL == host )
    {
        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(&sock_addr, '\0', sizeof(sock_addr));
    sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy( &sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            host -> h_addr,
            host -> h_length );

    sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr)) == -1)
    {
        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    if( write(sockfd, headers, strlen(headers) + 1) == -1)
    {
        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    buffer = malloc( MAX_BUFFER_SIZE );
    tbuf = malloc( MAX_BUFFER_SIZE );

    if(buffer == NULL || tbuf == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int bytesloaded = 0;
    int readed;

    while( (readed = read(sockfd, tbuf, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0 )
    {   

        if(bytesloaded + readed >= buf_size)
        {
            buf_size = buf_size + MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;  
            newbuf = realloc(buffer, buf_size);

            if(newbuf != NULL)
               buffer = newbuf; 
            else 
              return NULL;
        }
          memcpy(buffer + bytesloaded, tbuf, readed);
      bytesloaded += readed;
    }

    //printf("bytesreaded = %d and buffer len is %d\n", bytesloaded, strlen(buffer));
    free(tbuf);
    close(sockfd);

    return buffer;
}
```

then:

`char * domain = "www.google.com\0";
    char * sheaders = "GET /images/srpr/logo3w.png HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.google.com\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n\n\0";
    int port = 80;
    char * response = httpget(domain, port, sheaders);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `str*` functions on arbitrary data. These are made to operate on C strings, which are zero-terminated. Binary data (most image formats) can contain zeros in the middle.

You should be using `memcpy`/`memmove`, and you have to rely on the return value of `read` to know how much data you actually got. `strlen` on binary data is meaningless.

Try replacing this part:

```
bytesloaded += readed;
strcat(buffer, tbuf);
```

With something like:

```
if (bytesloaded+readed >= buf_size) {
  // do the realloc now
}
memcpy(buffer+bytesloaded, tbuf, readed);
bytesloded += readed;
```

`buffer + x` (with `x` an integer type whose value is less than the allocated buffer size) is a pointer to the `x`th char in `buffer`. (This is pointer arithmetic. The type of `buffer` matters. In this case, it is invalid if `x` is negative.)
You need to perform the re-allocation before you attempt the `memcpy` otherwise you risk writing past the end of the buffer.
`memcpy` is safe here because you know that `buffer` and `tbuf` don't overlap.

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you give me an example? I have tried it, but `memcpy()`/`memmove()` does not concat the string like `strcat()`, then, In buffer I have only the last value passed as argument.

Comment: Added one variation on how you could do this.

Comment: :Thanks again. Well, I replace by `memcpy(buffer + bytesloaded, tbuf, readed);` but it copies only the HTTP headers and `�PNG\n` how to fix this? check out my code update.

Comment: To the OP: you are not checking the return value from write(). It should be done similar to that of read(). You should also find a way to return not only the pointer-to-the-result-buffer to the caller, but also it's length.

Comment: @wildplasser: I will make a new variable and store the buffer length on it. But how do I could check write() size? I check just if it does not return -1(erro).

Comment: Just as with read(), it returns the amount that was **actually** written. (or zero, or -1).